# What is the function of clot retraction?

Tags: physiology, hematology

I am thinking how clot retraction and fibrinolysis work together.
I think that clot retraction is a process that gets clot towards fibrinolysis process.
Fibrinolysis process then lyses the clot.
However, I am not sure if it is so simple.

Some seems to be discussing about how to differentiate start of fibrinolysis from clot retraction morphologically.
So they probably seem to be at this stage similar processes visually, but not functionally.

**What is the function of clot retraction?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The platelets in the clot contain contractile proteins. They bring the edges of the wound together, which also reduces the chance of further bleeding. The contraction process also supports the wound healing process as it brings the ends of the wound together.

For more information see this article: "[Mechanics and contraction dynamics of single platelets and implications for clot stiffening](http://www.nature.com/nmat/journal/v10/n1/abs/nmat2903.html)"

Comment: So these contractile proteins cause the clot retraction. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Is this different type of contraction than vasocontraction? It seems to be so.